# id selector blocks changes in element hover

Tags: html, css

I have 5 paragraphs and a paragraph nested in a div like in the code below, the problem is with `p:hover{background-color: gray;}`, it should change the background of all paragraphs but it doesn't change the ones which have id attribute or are nested inside a div which has id attribute.

```css
p {
  background-color: brown;
  padding: 10px;
}

.p1 {
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

.p2 {
  background-color: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
}

#p1 {
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
}

#p2 {
  background-color: orangered;
}

#d1 {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  padding: 5px;
}

#d1 p {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}

p:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<p>This is a normal paragraph</p>
<p class="p1">This is a paragraph with class attribute "p1"</p>
<p class="p2">This is a paragraph with class attribute "p2"</p>
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph with id attribute "p1"</p>
<p id="p2">This is a paragraph with id attribute "p2"</p>

<div id="d1">
  <p>This is a paragraph nested in a div of id equal to "d1"</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You requirement isn't clear

Comment: Sounds like a [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: @j08691 thanks for the link, adding `!important` at the end of `background-color` in `p:hover` works, but why does it happen in the first place?

Comment: @j08691 Please answer the full explanation and correct code so i can check as the correct answer.